# emtpy cells and sort not consistant

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with what seems to be a non-consistant way for excel to manage empty cells when using sort.
when I enter data manually, ascending sort put the empty cells at the end, when I enter the data via copy and paste, ascending sort put the empty cells at the beginning. Did I miss something?

same issue when sorting using VBA range.sort method.

Any Idea about what is going on here is welcome.

Thanks

here is a file that illustrates the issue.

https://www.cjoint.com/c/JCbjMc1x0E5

select column B then sort and see the result. -
do the same with column C.

I made some more investigations and the problem doesn't seem to be related to the copy and paste but to a difference between the 2 sets of data. But I don't see any (same format, same content, ...)

Comment: The "blank" cells at the source of your Copy/Paste aren't blank. They might contain a single space or a non-printing character that looks like a space. Test with `=CODE(A1)`. A blank will give a #VALUE error.

Comment: I have experienced the same phenomenon. It's a good issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce - can you include steps to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Depends on what you are sorting.  True blanks will sort to the bottom.  `Space`s will sort between numbers and letters.  So if your copy/paste data consists of Spaces and letters; and your manually entered data has no spaces (or no letters), you can see what you have reported.  If, in both cases, the blank cells are truly empty, then I cannot reproduce what you report.

Comment: If you were to include the code you are using in your question, then the people here to help you wouldn't have to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: @ all thanks for your comments and reaction. I have added a file that demonstrates the issue. @brax no code is used as the problem occurs with excel sort within the data menu. (but same issue with vba sort)

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the empty cells that are not of the same type. When the empty cells are of type 2 (=text), The ascending sort put them first, when the empty cells are of type 1 (=number), the ascending sort put them last. The next question is why do those empty cells receive a type 2, but this is another question.

ps. to visualize the type of cell, use the excel =type() function.

Thanks everybody!